# JavaFX2-fxml tag for menu and sub-menu

Tags: java, contextmenu, javafx-2, javafx, fxml

how can I use `FXML` to create sub-menu ? I have done it in java in start method but I would like to move my code to `FXML`. please check `item2`, where I have added 2 `submenus`.

```
 ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
    Menu item2 = new Menu("Actions");
    MenuItem item7 = new MenuItem("Close All");

    MenuItem subMenu1 = new MenuItem("Save");
    MenuItem subMenu2 = new MenuItem("Save As..");

    item2.getItems().addAll(subMenu1, subMenu2);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, I recommend checking out [SceneBuilder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/tools/index.html). For all it's quirks, it's a great tool for learning FXML layout.

Second, this should get you going in the right direction.

```
<Menu text="Actions" fx:id="item2">
  <items>
    <MenuItem text="Save" fx:id="subMenu1" />
    <MenuItem text="Save As.." fx:id="subMenu2" />
  </items>
</Menu>
```